# sending a message to an Azure Iot hub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub, scada

I'm a beginner to AzureIot, I've been given access to an azure account which has an IOT hub.
from the azure portal I see a connection string of the form:
`HostName=iothub-mycompany.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=_somekey_in_base64_`

Now all I need is to simply **send a JSON payload to this IOT hub**. Any protocol would do.

I was **assuming** that when I send a message I can see this message with the [this device explorer tool](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer). but I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or perhaps there is a flaw in my understanding.

I tried examples from blogs, msdn etc In the end I've come up with the code below

It runs, however I have no clue what it's doing and **where to look for whether this message was sent**.

- The Device explorer shows nothing.
- I checked the Activity Login portal.azure.com but it seems more like a login activity log.
- Also in the azure portal Under explorers I See Iot Devices. I see the device name I need to target.(I know it exists)

Here is the code, part of .Net4.5.2 ConsoleApplication.

`Program.cs`:

```
class Program
{
    static DeviceClient deviceClient;
    const string IOT_HUB_CONN_STRING = "connection str in format specified above.";
    const string IOT_HUB_DEVICE_LOCATION = "_some_location.";
    const string IOT_HUB_DEVICE = "device_id";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ret = SendMessageToIoTHubAsync("temperature", 15);


        Console.WriteLine("completed:" + ret.IsCompleted);


    }
    private static async Task SendMessageToIoTHubAsync(string sensorType, int sensorState)
    {
        deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(IOT_HUB_CONN_STRING, TransportType.Mqtt);//i tried other trsnsports
        try
        {
            var payload = "{" +
                "\"deviceId\":\"" + IOT_HUB_DEVICE + "\", " +
                "\"location\":\"" + IOT_HUB_DEVICE_LOCATION + "\", " +
                "\"sensorType\":\"" + sensorType + "\", " +
                "\"sensorState\":" + sensorState + ", " +
                "\"localTimestamp\":\"" + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() + "\"" +
                "}";

            var msg = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));

            Debug.WriteLine("\t{0}> Sending message: [{1}]", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), payload);

            await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("!!!! " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note, my "device" is [ClearScada](http://software.schneider-electric.com/products/clearscada/). I will have C# Driver which will get data out of a ClearScada instance, this driver should send that data to the azure iot hub. <sub>essentially I just need to figure the sending from C#
 to Azure iot.</sub>
**Questions:**

- Where Can I see my messages.?
- Is my function correct or is there a flaw in my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

> - Where Can I see my messages.?

You can see your messages in the Device Explorer like this:

[image]

> - Is my function correct or is there a flaw in my understanding.

There are two issues to your function:

- First, you need use device specified connection string instead of
  Azure IoT Hub connection string. It has the following format:

  "HostName=[YOUR HUB NAME].azure-devices.net;DeviceId=[DEVICE ID];SharedAccessKey=[DEVICE KEY]"

You can easily get this connection string via Device Explorer like this:

[image]

- Second, your program exits before the sending operation completely.
  You can avoid this happening by adding `Console.ReadLine();` like
  this:

[image]

**Update:**

[Retrieving the value of the Task.IsCompleted property does not block the calling thread until the task has completed.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You can edit your `main` method like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ret = SendMessageToIoTHubAsync("temperature", 15);

        ret.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("completed:" + ret.IsCompleted);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Does `isCompleted` provide any guarantee the Task **finished**? Is that an acceptable way to block for result in Main (a non-async Main that is) vs `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`?